# Why do I get There are no registered serializers for type "google.VertexEndpoint"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kfp

I am trying to deploy a model using `ModelDeployOp` in a Vertex AI pipeline component. My code is:

```
parent = client.common_location_path(project=project, location=location)
request = aiplatform_v1.ListEndpointsRequest(parent=parent)

page_result = client.list_endpoints(request=request)
for response in page_result:
     latest_endpoint=response


deploy_op=gcc_aip.ModelDeployOp(
model=model_name,
endpoint=latest_endpoint,
dedicated_resources_min_replica_count=1,
dedicated_resources_max_replica_count=1,
dedicated_resources_machine_type="n1-standard-4",
)
```

but i get:

```
TypeError: There are no registered serializers for type "google.VertexEndpoint".
```

How can I fix this or maybe find a better way of getting the endpoint?

Comment: I have a similar error: `There are no registered serializers for type "Artifact"`.

Could you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, don't have access to it any more. I think I gave up and did something else.